# Where is the "project file"?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have created a .NET7 C# project, and I'm trying to understand this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/desktop/winforms/whats-new/net60?view=netdesktop-6.0#new-application-bootstrap about the new bootstrap that moves the configurations to the "project file":

> To complement the new application bootstrap feature of Windows Forms, a few Application
> settings previously set in the startup code of the application should be set in the project
> file. The project file can configure the following application settings:

The only thing it doesn't mention is where can we find the *project file*? Is it editable from Visual Studio directly? Or we have to create it for ourselves?

Comment: That’s the csproj file

Comment: The Visual Studio does manage the project file. It is created automatically when you create a project so... It should be inside your solution folder and you could edit it manually but you should not do it unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: a proj file, csproj, vbproj etc. is a command or driver file for the compiler - how to compile your code

Comment: *"where can we find the project file?"* if you use `dotnet` - in the "current command" folder. If you use VS - where you selected its location using dialog.

Comment: In the Solution Explorer rigth click on project name > Edit Project File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio explorer, double click on the file with "csproj" extension (it has a rectangular icon with C# written in green. This will open the file in xml format. In most cases, you don't need to manipulate it manually.

[image]

Comment: On VS2022, it's even enough to click only once on it :)

Comment: So, you learned two things today :)